# What is causing this Kernel panic (Unable to mount root fs)?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have a simple question for the gurus...
How bad is this?

[image: screenshot]

A few days ago I was using my laptop and next day I have this on the screen.
So I installed the HDD on my desktop to see if I can get all my stuff from the disk, but I can't.
This is the message when I try to boot with this HDD.

Comment: Thank you! Is my first use of a blog plus my English is not so good

Comment: It looks bad... try fsck from live disk... looks like damage to me...

Answer (score 0):

`Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)` means that you did not tell the kernel what to mount as your root directory.  This is normal because instead of having the kernel do this directly, these days it is handed an initramfs that takes care of locating and mounting the root filesystem, but for some reason, your initramfs is missing.  Use the grub menu to choose an older kernel that may still have its initramfs so you can boot up, then run `sudo update-initramfs -u` to rebuild the initramfs.

Comment: I did all that and from other post too.. and is not working